# How to install Symfony2 Bundles with Composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, doctrine-migrations

I'm using Windows and I installed composer from its Windows installer. What I want to do is to install [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) to my project, so I added

`"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"`

to the `composer.json` file in the project and run

```
cd the project directory
php composer.phar update
```

but what I get is: Could not open input file: composer.phar

My whole composer.json file is

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev"
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said by @AhmedSiouani, the error tells you that they can't find a `composer.phar` file.

Some things you can do:

1. Download the `Composer-SetUp.exe` and install Composer as told on [the downloads page](http://getcomposer.org/download/) (scroll to 'Windows Installer');
2. Download the `composer.phar` file and put that in your project (not recommend);
3. Download the `composer.phar` file and put that in a directory which is in your `PATH` environment variable<sup>1</sup>;
4. Download the `composer.phar` file and create a `composer.bat` file which executes the `composer.phar` file. Put the code below in it and save it in a directory which is in your `PATH` environment variable<sup>1</sup>.

   ```
   @echo off
   php "path\to\composer.phar" %*
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>: You can see which directories are in the `PATH` environment variable by 
running `echo %PATH%` in your cmd.
You can also put the directory where this file lives in the `PATH` environment. To do that, go to *`Computer` (right click) > `Settings` > `Advanced Settings` > `Environments Variables` (under the 'advanced' tab)* and set the PATH variable with your directory path (or add the path to the current PATH variable, by putting a `;` between the paths).

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear enough, it's not related to your `composer.json` file.

I think you just need to move your `composer.phar` file to your project directory.

Also, a much reusable solution would be to call it through your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue with me "Could not open input file: composer.phar"

Fix : Go to the project directory and run following command

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

and run

```
php composer.phar install or php composer.phar update
```

This will work awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I working on fedora 17 I ran it on console to download **composer.phar** :

```
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

then it's work now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code:

```
 "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev"
 "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
```

is changed to:

```
"kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
 "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
```

notice adding a , (comma).