# Installing behat with mink on windows using composer

Tags: json, composer-php, behat, mink

I am trying to install mink/behat on windows machine using composer by following the help given on behat page. http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html.

But when I run

`php composer.phar install`

then I get the error

[image]

But I have composer.json(exactly same as described in behat page) file in mentioned directory. Can someone please guide me how can I install it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer installs packages on project-base. I don't think you have a PHP project inside `C:\Windows\system32`...

Navigate to your project by using `cd` (**c**hange **d**ir) and be sure the `composer.phar` file is automatically loaded in every directory (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226430/1149495)).

Then create a `composer.json` file in which you put the things that is stated in the docs.

After that run `composer install` (or `php composer.phar install`, depends on which install method you used).

Comment: Thanks. I have already got it running. And got rid of the problem by doing exactly as you described.